# Create new array of objects by grouping array of objects based on property value of each object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like below, I want to create new array of objects by grouping array of java script objects based on property value of each object in java script

Here I want to group objects based on Group ID and store it into an array of object with unique group ID.

This is my object:

```
var Object = [
 {"Name":15,"GroupID":1,"ComplexObject":1}`object1`    
 {"Name":16,"GroupID":1,"ComplexObject":1}`object2`   
 {"Name":17,"GroupID":2,"ComplexObject":2}`object3
 {"Name":18,"GroupID":2,"ComplexObject":2}`object4`
 {"Name":15,"GroupID":3,"ComplexObject":3}`object5`
 {"Name":16,"GroupID":3,"ComplexObject":3}`object6`
 {"Name":17,"GroupID":4,"ComplexObject":4}`object7`
 {"Name":18,"GroupID":4,"ComplexObject":4}`object8` ];
```

Comment: `var Object = ` ... not sure javascript would like `Object` being overridden!

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_arr = [];

Objects.forEach(function(object) {
  if (new_arr.length <= object.GroupID) {
    new_arr[object.GroupID] = [];
  }
  new_arr[object.GroupID].push(object);
});
```

**Update:** if you want the length of the array, just use:

```
var new_arr = [];

Objects.forEach(function(object) {
  if (new_arr.length < object.GroupID) {
    new_arr[object.GroupID - 1] = [];
  }
  new_arr[object.GroupID - 1].push(object);
});
```

and you will get this:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks iplus. I am getting the length as 5, because the ID starts from 1, So 0th element is undefined.. Any other way to store...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way by checking the group id and pushing it to the array object.

```
  var data = [ 
                {"Name":15,"GroupID":1,"ComplexObject":1},
                {"Name":16,"GroupID":1,"ComplexObject":1},
                {"Name":17,"GroupID":2,"ComplexObject":2},
                {"Name":18,"GroupID":2,"ComplexObject":2},
                {"Name":15,"GroupID":3,"ComplexObject":3},
                {"Name":16,"GroupID":3,"ComplexObject":3},
                {"Name":17,"GroupID":4,"ComplexObject":4},
                {"Name":18,"GroupID":4,"ComplexObject":4}
             ];

  console.log("Original Data : ", data);

  var previousGroupId;
  var newObject = new Object();
  for(index in data){
      var groupId = data[index].GroupID;
      if(groupId != previousGroupId){
          var newGroup = "GroupId" + groupId;
          newObject[newGroup] = new Array();
          for(index in data){
              if(data[index].GroupID == groupId){
                  var customObject = {
                      "GroupID" : groupId,
                      "Name" : data[index].Name,
                      "ComplexObject" : data[index].ComplexObject
                  };
                  newObject[newGroup].push(customObject);        
              }
          }
      }
      previousGroupId = groupId;
  }

  console.log("Grouped data : ", newObject);
```

[***jsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/9od4fpe6/)

Comment: Hi Ashad, Thanks for the prompt response. I want this to be stored in array of object, not in object. I want to get the length of the array and have to do some operations based on length.